# Parallel execution in Selenium testcases in testng

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I tried to run my `Selenium` scripts in parallel and configured my TestNG suite as

```
<test name="Test" parallel="classes" thread-count="3" preserve-order="true">
```

This runs my test cases in parallel launching 3 browser instance at a time. This works fine in couple of laptop(Having Windows 7 OS) that I tried. But when I try to run the same on a Windows 2008 Server OS it does not work -- only one thread is launched at a time. What is the root cause ?

Comment: Can you put your code here

Comment: Which part of code do i need to put here ,because scripts are written in top of a framework that is developed